# Export SO Developer Story to devstory.fyi

Tags: app, stackoverflow

#### About

[devstory.fyi](https://devstory.fyi?utm_campaign=launch&utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=social) allows you to [import](https://devstory.fyi/users/story/preview?utm_campaign=launch&utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=social) your SO Developer Story so you can continue to manage it once SO [sunsets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story) this feature.

You can import and fully manage your story. You can share (if you want) a public url. You can also download your data in **JSON resume** format without creating an account. See steps outlined in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416753/823967).

#### Demo

You can see my So Developer Story [here](https://stackoverflow.com/story/jonlunsford) and the imported **DevStory** [here](https://devstory.fyi/jonlunsford). Try previewing yours [here](https://devstory.fyi/users/story/preview?utm_campaign=launch&utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=social).

[image]

#### Road Map

I prioritized importing data over a few niceties, so far the tentative plan is to implement:

1. ✅ Rich text editing (markdown).
2. ✅ Export as [JSON resume](https://jsonresume.org/schema/) - [demo (GH gist)](https://gist.github.com/jonlunsford/78da98637858ed7e796b171c03bb6ec3)
3. ✅ Traditional view. ([demo](https://devstory.fyi/cv/jonlunsford))
4. ✅ Mobile friendly layouts
5. ✅ Technologies tagging.
6. Export as PDF
7. Integrations: Github, Bitbucket, Pluralsight.

##### What else would help showcase your developer history?

Comment: You can compare https://stackoverflow.com/story/vonc and https://developerstory.dev/story/vonc. In both case, having the option to also get the classic resume page would be a plus.

Comment: @VonC Github flavored markdown is now supported on all text inputs, I also fixed up some formatting quirks. The classic resume view is coming next, once that's implemented then PDF exports will be possible. Let me know if any issues jump out and any recommendations you have for improvement, check out your story here: [https://devstory.fyi/vonc](https://devstory.fyi/vonc)

Comment: Nice! Thank you. I will test it out tomorrow (a bit late for me today)

Comment: @VonC see the "traditional view" [here](https://devstory.fyi/cv/vonc) let me know what you think. I will have the PDF export available shortly.

Comment: Looking good, except for some line overlaps (in story as well as in CV). Will the HTML import be converted automatically to markdown, for easy edit later on?

Comment: Thanks @VonC! Took me a minute to realize the visual issues were in Firefox :( I've since fixed those. And yes, the import will now convert HTML to markdown. All of your HTML, at least that was able, has been converted as to Markdown now as well.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. I will have a look a do some edits.

Comment: Comparison between different options is here: https://dev.to/dbonillaf/how-to-survive-the-stackoverflowgeddon-7o2 I would like all the options share the same format, like MAC json export, so we developers can be free to put hour CV in one or several places at the same time. One format to rule them all..

Comment: It seems we now have even alternatives, see answer: https://stackapps.com/questions/9361/how-to-export-so-developer-story-to-a-standard-open-source-json-format/9362