# A service to help people to download their Dev Stories before the Stack Overflow DS sunset

Tags: script

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: SOgeddon landing capture]

[image: SOgeddon console capture]

### About

Manfred launches a website that allows any StackOverflow user to download their Developer Story data as a JSON file, without requiring registering or providing any email address.
For free. Open Source. For the community.

#### License

Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike 4.0 International

#### Download

- Source Code at https://github.com/getmanfred/dev-story-scraper
- Service at https://getmanfred.com/stackoverflowgeddon

#### Platform

As a service it can be accessed from any device with Internet connection using a simple browser.
To launch it in your local machine, you can use Windows, Linux, or macOS as the main operating systems.

### Contact

The application was developed by the team at http://getmanfred.com (https://github.com/getmanfred)
The main developers for the scraper are:

- Yeray Darias (https://github.com/ydarias)
  @ydarias
  at Twitter
- David Bonilla (https://github.com/dbonillaf)
  @david_bonilla
  at Twitter

### Code

The scraper is implemented using TypeScript.
The code can be downloaded from https://github.com/getmanfred/dev-story-scraper
It is open source, to contribute you just need to create a PR.